# Sitecore 8 installation on Azure

Tags: azure, sitecore, azure-sql-database, sitecore8

I am new to Site core world and planning to deploy Site core 8 on Microsoft Azure for my organization.

Few questions wherein need valuable assistance -

a) What are the roles of SQL Azure Core, Web & Master and what are the recommended architecture?

b) Will DB in cloud will be common for Production, Staging & Test Environment?

c) Can I get the Trail license to install and play with Site core 8 and understand its function and deployment architecture?

d) Blueprint on Site core 8 deployment for different environments in Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try my best to refer you with some resources available on sitecore.

For questions related to cloud deployment you can check Sitecore Azure module documentation.
Depending on application requirement you can go for IaaS and PaaS

https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure

**Sitecore License**
I am not sure whether sitecore provides such evaluation licenses, however if your organization is Sitecore partner you can request partner licenses. I would suggest you to get in touch with your regional sitecore contact person to get more information.

Hope this will help you to get started!